# curl vs. wget produce different redirects and results

Tags: http, redirect, curl, wget

The following URL was posted in another question.

Using wget you get the csv file as expected, but `curl` ends up redirected you to something different. I was wondering what the differences are between the two commands or how to get the same result in `curl`.

### wget

```
wget --output-document=test.csv --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv'
```

### curl

```
curl --location --insecure --output test.csv 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv'
```

---

### Updated with header information

#### header comparison

#### wget 1

```
--2014-07-03 09:54:30--  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv
Resolving docs.google.com... 74.125.226.98, 74.125.226.100, 74.125.226.102, ...
Connecting to docs.google.com|74.125.226.98|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
  Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:54:30 GMT
  X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
  Location: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&sa=p
  Set-Cookie: NID=67=D4vu38cFuNFB-qdFSdaVBpLKJ94VcnpcVDfEpoyECGG-EesJlxBW4Rwb-AA-XAF7ztGOAIzx3u2YYqwRlt516cv3i6jSa9Pazf3uK-hyR5p5QoEYaZ-MqRpj9H_utLwU;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 02-Jan-2015 13:54:30 GMT;HttpOnly
  P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Server: GSE
  Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&sa=p [following]
```

#### curl 1

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:48 GMT
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
Location: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&sa=p
Set-Cookie: NID=67=QTFWWFkySepW985crZ2dZk1JfQ8gGj_H59HwYp-SMcOvYl0J4JU3VfDGCqppxFcEPt-e48qr0yJOx2ImUKH65LlgvuLyF3Ec842bPFq-BFg9a7YWEP_5Uq8YJrJ58taL;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 02-Jan-2015 13:59:48 GMT;HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

#### wget 2

```
--2014-07-03 09:54:30--  https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&sa=p
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.225.144, 74.125.225.145, 74.125.225.148, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.225.144|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
  Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv&pref=2
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=1f6208c8ba0c71f9:FF=0:TM=1404395670:LM=1404395670:S=HaS679Z5xbmJBKs7; expires=Sat, 02-Jul-2016 13:54:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
  Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:54:30 GMT
  Server: gws
  Content-Length: 311
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv&pref=2 [following]
```

#### curl 2

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv&pref=2
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=432f03534cff2fd2:FF=0:TM=1404395989:LM=1404395989:S=1NwOiUYJQYKfn6qF; expires=Sat, 02-Jul-2016 13:59:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=EjeYW1PP63Nxk5upQVhEVreT_prZXQYQy4WVKZCHkY3cXffcTWyvXIJkt4Tg07LUoHo3GSkEg6qDh5ff5ESGhksbjT50ytYRd0SyKp7quyorpbT4GMhnbORlkFfTNdRc; expires=Fri, 02-Jan-2015 13:59:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 311
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

#### wget 3

```
--2014-07-03 09:54:31--  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv&pref=2
Connecting to docs.google.com|74.125.226.98|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv
  Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:54:31 GMT
  Expires: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:54:31 GMT
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Server: GSE
  Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv [following]
```

#### curl 3

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&followup=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&ltmpl=sheets
Content-Length: 2270
Set-Cookie: NID=67=NdTD41weGlHPUtsUMwF0a7ugZ5Hfof3Q8CFsy2gQcJuBaH8ugZIYppe2PWWhP5fEMtdToEi76-lQH_lAJUeLEkNo1nObesgzEnSSg3HEJeb-5vYrAs4fwR7bM7Ourxeh;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 02-Jan-2015 13:59:49 GMT;HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Expires: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
```

#### wget 4 (final)

```
--2014-07-03 09:54:31--  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv
Reusing existing connection to docs.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
  Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:54:31 GMT
  X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Download Test Spreadsheet.csv"
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Server: GSE
  Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

#### curl 4

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fccc%3Fkey%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheet%2Fccc%3Fkey%3D0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc%26output%3Dcsv%26pref%3D2&ltmpl=sheets
Content-Length: 556
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Expires: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

#### curl 5 (final)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10893354; includeSubDomains
Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:v3eXsN1lqmN5ryz1eyf2iMBP2uoIGg:wiYHYyLrGeoRHUfk;Path=/;Expires=Sat, 02-Jul-2016 13:59:49 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly;Priority=HIGH
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Expires: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:59:49 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

Comment: What result does curl produce, other than "redirect to something different"?

Comment: Well ultimately wget downloads the csv file and curl downloads an entire html page that has nothing to do with the csv.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details than that. Currently, I get a 404 Not Found for the URL's in the question. A great starting point is the verbose output by both Curl and Wget. An even better thing would be to supply the debug logs of both.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've fixed up the 404 error from the wget command and added in a header comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a great debugging-technique is to open that link while having the developer toolbar open in chrome and look at the network-tab. all requests in that tab can be right-clicked to show the cURL command to download that information.

in your case, the issue seems to be that wget is handling cookies for you, while cURL does not. this should be easy to fix:

```
curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv' --location --cookie tmp.cookie
# Foo,Bar,Baz
# 1,2,3
# 4,5,6
```